# How to effectively manage the marklogic content size via DLS

Tags: marklogic

I am using marklogic [dls](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls) to manage the document version and backup. There are still some concepts I am not clear, although I did some real testing with the dls.

In order to better explain the question, I am following the exact the same test case in https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls to create the /engineering/beta_overview.xml sample data in content db. Here is what it looks like when I browse it via qconsole.

[image: File Listing]

Here is what the retention-rules in db when I query from qconsole.
[image: qconsole query retention rules]

Here is the xqy code how I construct the retention rule.
[image: xqy code for retention rules]

Questions

1. What will happen if there is no retention rule defined in DB? Will DLS still work normally?
2. Where the retention rule is stored? Is there a way to define retention rule for all ML content dbs? Or retention rule is per content db level?
3. If there are multiple retention rules for the very same document, basically the most "relaxed" version will apply. In other words, the one that keep the most number of version of copy will apply. It is the "OR" coverage. Am I right?
4. Why I could not see the original retention query when I query `dls:retention-rules("*")`? It seems it got replaced with some cts:key. How to see what the key really means?
   (We might get lost of the retention rules over time. People may query from DB to see the what it actually is. )

5. Is it possible to define retention rules via gradle? Any example?
6. What are those empty files (1) part in file listing? How to clean those up?
   I understand (2) are the actual back up copies of different versions of the files.
   The current copy is the (3).

Or those (1) could not be purged, as they are empty and they do not take up space? I am lost for that concept.

7. As the rule defines a duration for 2 Days only. When and how the backup in (2) part will be deleted? Must I run `dls:purge` command?
8. What is retain-history parameter in dls:purge? What is the use case?
   [image: dls:purge help]

Comment: that's an awful lot of questions